# React run javascript code after all render is completed in function based component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, jsx

I had a form component with the following content

```
function Form() {
    return (
    <div className="form-container">
        <div className="form-control">
            <label id="text-input">Text </label>
            <input type="text"></input>
        </div>
        <div className="form-control">
            <label>Time </label>
            <input type="text"></input>
        </div>
        <div className="form-control" style={{alignItems:"center"}}>
            <button className="add-but">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

I wanted to focus the text element after the component gets rendered.
I was first trying to put `{document.querySelector("#txt-in").focus()}`, it didn't work and after searching I found I could use the tag `autoFocus`. and everything would work beautifully.

But I was wondering, what if I want to actually execute javascript code after rendering? or actually do this in javascript? I found answers for `class` based components but couldn't find for `function` based components like the one I am using.

how do I execute code I want executed after the element is rendred, in function based components?

Comment: You can do that using `useEffect` function if you are using react hooks or `lifecycle methods` from the react class.

Comment: For this you need a useRef hook https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use React Hooks `useEffect` for your purpose.

Simply put below code

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";

function Form() {

 useEffect(() => {
    // Do whatever you want after first render
    // Put your code here
 }, [])

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what the components are writing, previously one would use functions like`componentDidUpdate` & `componentDidMount` to manipulate components after/before being rendered. Funcitonal components realised we could use one 'hook' for this called `useEffect` where one can trigger a particular action to occur on the basis of a state change to the component.

Here is a link to the docs for `useEffect` - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html